# Удаление столбцов в переборе python

Tags: python, dataframe

Изучаю python для ИИ

Я хочу научиться работать с большими данными. Есть данные о пользователях - таблица из n столбцов, которые обрабатываются через логическую регрессию.

Столбцы имеют различные типы, которые я заранее преобразованию.

Мне нужна помощь в придумывании алгоритма откидывания менее значимых столбцов для анализа данных.

То есть придумать метод для перебора всех возможных откидывания столбцов (всех вариантов исключений), чтобы в первом случае убрали лишь первый, во втором второй, а в n третий и пятый
Если есть статьи, которые я пропустил или уже готовые решения, то всегда рад самостоятельно изучить

Comment: Вы желаете получить именно все варианты откидывания или найти метод, который позволит вам оптимально их откинуть с точки зрения дальнейшей обработки?

Comment: @EzikBro да это

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитайте для начала какие варианты отбора фич предлагает популярная библиотека `scikit-learn`: [Feature selection](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html)

На самом деле это довольно широкая и неоднозначная тема. Отбор фич может хорошо себя показать на одних данных (тренировочных) и плохо на других (тестовых). А может при небольшой потере в качестве значительно ускорить анализ данных. А может даже и наоборот улучшить качество. Случаи разные бывают.

В продвинутых алгоритмах машинного обучения вроде `Random Forest` или `XGBoost` есть встроенные мерилки полезности фич, можно ими воспользоваться для отбора фич.

И есть ещё `permutation importance`, с помощью которой тоже можно отбирать фичи, но по моему опыту она тоже штука неоднозначная, всё надо пробовать на конкретных данных.

А ещё есть такие библиотеки для автоматизированного отбора фич, как [Boruta](https://github.com/scikit-learn-contrib/boruta_py) и [BoostARoota](https://github.com/chasedehan/BoostARoota). У второй библиотеки, кстати, хорошо расписано, как она собственно отбирает фичи, это полезно почитать.

Comment: `всё надо пробовать на конкретных данных` - полностью подтверждаю. `Feature importance` из "лесных" алгоритмов вслепую доверять нельзя, надо обязательно сравнивать производительность до и после отбрасывания "незначительных" признаков.

Comment: @MaxU Да и вообще это очень итеративный и творческий процесс. Был бы однозначно хороший метод, все бы им пользовались. Но "серебряной пули" пока нет, насколько я понимаю. )